# How to centre a colorbar at a defined value for seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I am trying to plot a heatmap using seaborn. I have values from 0 to 5 and I need to make a blue-to-red color scale, with white being at 1, blue- below 1, and red - from 1 to 5.

How can I do that?

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
hm=sns.heatmap(proportion, vmin=0, vmax=5, cmap='RdBu')
```

This is what I try to do, but it is not customized... 'proportion' is my variable. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Do you want to have 3 colors, or a gradient?

Comment: I will definitely need a gradient...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe you mean to use the `center` argument,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10,10)*5

ax = sns.heatmap(data, vmin=0,vmax=5,center=1,cmap="RdBu_r")

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!