# Python: Shifted logarithmic colorbar, white color offset to center

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am struggling to plot my data using `pyplot.imshow`. I use the 'RdBu_r' colormap, and I need the white color to be at value 1 on a logarithmic scale which is not centered at 1. But how can I do it?
I tried 'center=1' which [works for seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589567/python-how-to-centre-a-colorbar-at-a-defined-value-for-seaborn-heatmap), but there is no such attribute in matplotlib. I also tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im=plt.imshow(proportion, cmap="RdBu_r", norm=LogNorm(), vmin=0.01, vmax=10)
axs=plt.gca()
cb = plt.colorbar(im, ax=axs,extend="both")
```

where `proportion` is my data array, ranging from 0.01 to 10. However there seems to be no way to specify that the white should be at 1 on this scale.
Is there a way to do that?

Note again that I need to make use a gradient of colors here and a logarithmic normalization.

Comment: Do you want to center the white color on `1` on a logarithmic scale? Is the `LogNorm()` part of the problem or an attempted solution? There are some posts about defining a midpoint on a colorscale, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144529/shifted-colorbar-matplotlib), which is also now part of the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html#custom-normalization-two-linear-ranges), also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404116/defining-the-midpoint-of-a-colormap-in-matplotlib) which shows some alternative attempts.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest LogNorm is part of the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some questions and answers about defining a midpoint on a colorscale. Especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144529/shifted-colorbar-matplotlib), which is also now part of the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html#custom-normalization-two-linear-ranges).

The idea is to subclass `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` and let it take a further argument `midpoint`. This can then be used to linearly interpolate the two ranges on either side of the midpoint to the ranges `[0,0.5]` and `[0.5,1]`.

To have a **midpoint on a logarithmic scale**, we can in principle do the same thing, just that we subclass `matplotlib.colors.LogNorm` and take the logarithm of all values, then interpolate this logarithm on the ranges `[0,0.5]` and `[0.5,1]`.

In the following example we have data between `0.001` and `10`. Using the usual `LogNorm` this results in the middle of the colormap (white in the case of the RdBu colormap) to be at `0.1`. If we want to have white at `1`, we specify `1` as the midpoint in the `MidPointLogNorm`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3,0,19), np.arange(10))
f = lambda x,y : 10**x*(1+y)
z = f(x,y)

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12,4.8))

im = ax.pcolormesh(x,y,z, cmap="RdBu_r", norm=LogNorm(vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max()))
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
ax.set_title("LogNorm")

class MidPointLogNorm(LogNorm):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        LogNorm.__init__(self,vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, clip=clip)
        self.midpoint=midpoint
    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # I'm ignoring masked values and all kinds of edge cases to make a
        # simple example...
        x, y = [np.log(self.vmin), np.log(self.midpoint), np.log(self.vmax)], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(np.log(value), x, y))


im2 = ax2.pcolormesh(x,y,z, cmap="RdBu_r", 
                            norm=MidPointLogNorm(vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), midpoint=1))
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("MidPointLogNorm")
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Updated solution which works for nan values: You need to replace the nan values by some value (best one outside the range of values from the array) then mask the array by those numbers. Inside the `MidPointLogNorm` we need to take care of nan values, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598291/how-to-obtain-transparency-for-masked-values-in-customised-colormap-matplotlib).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3,0,19), np.arange(10))
f = lambda x,y : 10**x*(1+y)
z = f(x,y)
z[1:3,1:3] = np.NaN

#since nan values cannot be used on a log scale, we need to change them to 
# something other than nan, 
replace = np.nanmax(z)+900
z = np.where(np.isnan(z), replace, z)
# now we can mask the array
z = np.ma.masked_where(z == replace, z)

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12,4.8))

im = ax.pcolormesh(x,y,z, cmap="RdBu_r", norm=LogNorm(vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max()))
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
ax.set_title("LogNorm")

class MidPointLogNorm(LogNorm):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        LogNorm.__init__(self,vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, clip=clip)
        self.midpoint=midpoint
    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        result, is_scalar = self.process_value(value)
        x, y = [np.log(self.vmin), np.log(self.midpoint), np.log(self.vmax)], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.array(np.interp(np.log(value), x, y), mask=result.mask, copy=False)


im2 = ax2.pcolormesh(x,y,z, cmap="RdBu_r", 
                            norm=MidPointLogNorm(vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), midpoint=1))
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("MidPointLogNorm")
plt.show()
```

Comment: That is very helpful! Could you also comment on what should I do to avoid NaN values in my data array?

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid"?

Comment: if I have several columns of nans which I need for my plot (otherwise I will have difficulties with axes and ticklabels), it says that all values must be positive... I can upload a picture if it makes it clearer...

Comment: You need to replace the nan values by some value number outside the range of values in the array, such that the logarithm can be taken of those values. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take the logarithm of your data before plotting it, then use `CenteredNorm` or `TwoSlopeNorm`, followed by using a `FuncFormatter` on the colorbar axis to undo your logarithm. It’s maybe a bit less elegant than the other answer but I think easier to understand and maintain, and doesn’t suffer from not being able to handle edge cases like NaNs because it uses built in `Norm`s.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import CenteredNorm, TwoSlopeNorm
import numpy as np

# Example data
x = y = np.linspace(0, 1, 21)
var = np.power(10, 2*(np.sin(10 * x)[:, np.newaxis] + np.cos(10 * y)[np.newaxis, :]) + 1)


# Transform data
base = 10
logvar = np.log(var)/np.log(base)

# Plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
im = ax.pcolormesh(y, x, logvar, cmap='bwr', norm=TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=0))
# For a symmetric colour scale with asymmetric data, use CenteredNorm

# Add a colorbar
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
# Place ticks at whole powers of the base.
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))
# Define your custom tick formatter function to undo the log transformation
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: f'${base:d}^{{{x:.0f}}}$'))

plt.show()
plt.close()
```